# Смысл названия романа "Тропик Рака"

Tags: общие-вопросы, семантика

Что означает название романа Генри Миллера "Тропик Рака"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас интересует, что означает название или сам термин? Не помня текста - не уверен даже, что читал, хотя название знакомое - просто не стал бы приводить сведения о самих тропиках. Насколько могу судить, действие романа происходит в Париже, и к реальным тропикам (линия вдоль 23-ей широты по обе стороны экватора) название отношения не имеет

Как и другого романа трилогии "Тропик Козерога", где действие происходит в Нью-Йорке. Скорее всего в обоих случаях это некий намек на зенит, кульминацию  эмоциональной жизни и самопознания человека. Больше ничего на ум не приходит.

А, вот нашел в английской вики

> Мiller wrote the book between 1930 and 1934 during his "nomadic life"
>   in Paris.[5]:105–107 As Miller discloses in the text of the book, he
>   first intended to title it "Crazy Cock".[6] Miller gave the following
>   explanation of why the book's title was Tropic of Cancer: "It was
>   because to me cancer symbolizes the disease of civilization, the
>   endpoint of the wrong path, the necessity to change course radically,
>   to start completely over from scratch.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropic_of_Cancer_(novel)

Ну в общем-то я был недалек от истины. Именно кульминация, перелом. Только не личности, а всего человечества в целом.

> Как Миллер раскрывает в тексте книги, он сначала намеревался назвать
>   его «Crazy Cock» [6]. Миллер дал следующее объяснение, почему название
>   книги было Tropic of Cancer: «Это было потому, что для меня рак
>   символизирует болезнь цивилизации, конечную точку неправильного пути,
>   необходимость радикального изменения курса, чтобы начать полностью с
>   нуля.

Comment: Да, именно смысл названия я хотел узнать. Спасибо, Мимоходов!

Answer (score 3):

**Тропик Рака** - параллель, по которой проходит северная граница *тропиков*; в их пределах возможно положение Солнца строго в зените. Термин ссылается также на *созвездие Рака*. Исторически это связано с положением Солнца в данном созвездии в момент летнего солнцестояния 2000 лет назад:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA

Comment: Благодарю, Alex_ander!